# PHP preg_replace_callback is there a way to break the search?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

Is there a way to break the search for `preg_replace_callback` when it reaches a certain index?

For example:

```
            $content = preg_replace_callback('/'.preg_quote($_POST['query'],'#').'/i', function($matches) use($replacements,&$index) {
                if ( $index > count($replacements) ) {
                    // I tried break; but doesn't work
                }

                if ( $replacements[$index] != '' ) {
                    $matches[0] = $replacements[$index];
                }
                $index++;
                return $matches[0];
            }, $content);
```

Comment: @Kasramvd I've added a sample code above.

Comment: `preg_quote($_POST['query'],'#')` doesn't make a lot of sense if your pattern delimiters are `/`.  Also, `#` is escaped by default so it is never an appropriate 2nd parameter of `preg_quote()`.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the elseif to ignore the second if

```
       $content = preg_replace_callback('/'.preg_quote($_POST['query'],'#').'/i', function($matches) use($replacements,&$index) {
            if ( $index > count($replacements) ) {
                // I tried break; but doesn't work
            } elseif ( $replacements[$index] != '' ) {
                $matches[0] = $replacements[$index];
            }
            $index++;
            return $matches[0];
        }, $content);
```

edit

```
preg_replace_callback ( mixed pattern, callback callback, mixed subject [, int limit [, int &count]] )
```

limit
The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to -1 (no limit).

count
If specified, this variable will be filled with the number of replacements done.

Comment: Is there no way to just stop the search?

Comment: Actualy you can limit the total replacements The only other way to do it is write your own function to loop through the array.